# How to check internet is reconnect or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

If there is no internet connection in my iPhone. And i want to fire an event when phone is connected to internet. Is there any method for that?? or should i check for internet connection after every 10 mins or something like that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below link, this will help you surely

[Reachablity checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk/3597085#3597085)

Happy coding